# How to open *.mui files in C:\Windows\System32\en-US?

Tags: windows, windows-mui

Is there any tool to open mui files or extract text recources from these files?
Want to extract these sentences as reference when writing lables and popup messages in our software.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

MUI is just DLLs with resource table.

You can use any resource editor like Resource Hacker, or Visual Studio.